# VBA/Macros: How to Split excel worksheets AND password protect each sheet with different passwords?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code which splits the worksheets into different workbooks, I'm trying to modify this code so that each file will be password protected before it is saved.

This is employee's salaries data which will need to be sent over to employee's every month so this 'master file' is what I'll be updating every month then I'll need the VBA to split these worksheets (payslips) and password protect them with their DOB in DDMMYYYY format (thus same password every month) which I can then forward it over to them via email.

Code:

```
Sub SplitEachWorksheet()
    Dim FPath As String
    FPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        ws.Copy
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & ws.Name & ".xlsx"
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Next

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

To perform your lookup of a passwords sheet and then assign the correspondening password to the sheet, you can use a function like this:

```
Function fn_GetPassword(str_SheetName As String) As String

On Error GoTo Err
    fn_GetPassword = Application.VLookup(str_SheetName, Sheets("Passwords").Range("A:B"), 2, 0)
    Exit Function

Err: '' Error handling if lookup value not found, return blank string
    fn_GetPassword = ""
    Debug.Print ("No allocated password found for: " & str_SheetName) '' Show debug for missing sheet password

End Function
```

And then use it like this:

```
Sub SplitEachWorksheet()
 
Dim FPath As String
FPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim str_tmpPW As String
 
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Name <> "Passwords" Then '' Do no save worksheet with all the passwords
        str_tmpPW = fn_GetPassword(ws.Name) '' Store password in temp variable
        If str_tmpPW <> "" Then '' Do not save workbook if no password set
            ws.Copy
            Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & ws.Name & ".xlsx", Password:=str_tmpPW
            Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        End If
    End If
Next
 
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   
End Sub
```

Passwords sheet can look like this:

[image: Passwords Sheet]

Obviously adjust your code as required. The code could be adjusted a bit more to factor in external workbooks, but for your needs it should hopefully suffice.
You will then need to consider how to keep your existing workbook secure, a) since you are storing salaries and b) since you are storing passwords.
But this is a matter beyond the scope of this query.

---

You were very close.

Just needed to add an additional qualifier in your SaveAs argument:

```
Password:="test"
```

Looks like this:

```
Sub SplitEachWorksheet()
 
Dim FPath As String
FPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    ws.Copy
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & ws.Name & ".xlsx", Password:="test"
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
 
Next
 
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   
End Sub
```

You will need to obviously use a variable instead of "test".

I presume you have a list of your DOBs that is associated with each sheet? So you can then just use that list.

Comment: Sorry I cannot code at all. Lets say I have a sheet called "Passwords" (in the same master file) Column A will be the worksheets name and Column B will have the DOB's. Please can you advise how the above macro can be configured? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user14639458 I've updated my answer to provide you an example of a Passwords sheet being referenced. Let me know if that helps

Comment: Genius! Thank you so much this works perfectly.